# TransformResponse in Axios breaks the response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have an Axios instance:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  responseType: 'json',
  baseURL: `...`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
  transitional: {
    forcedJSONParsing: true,
    silentJSONParsing: false,
  },
});
```

I have also a very simple `GET` call:

```
const login = () => {
  return axiosInstance.get('/auth/login', {
    transformResponse: ({ data }) => {
      return camelcaseKeys(data);
    },
  });
};
```

However, after updating Axios to v1, the `transformResponse` function breaks my app. If I console.log the response, it's non-parsed JSON. But if I *remove* the `transformResponse` function, it is parsed properly and I'm getting the response as JS object, not a JSON string.

Why does the `transformResponse` function break everything? And why is it causing Axios to not parse JSON?

The request headers is:

```
Accept: application/json
```

The response headers is:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8
```

Also what is very strange, is that my code editor grays out the `transformResponse` function, and before Axios update it didn't.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsQkj.png)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `transformResponse: (data) => { return camelcaseKeys(data); },` (or just `transformResponse: camelcaseKeys,`)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe doesnt really matter, still breaks the parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the official example for `transformResponse` https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v1.x/examples/transform-response/index.html

The correct way to use it seems to be like the following

```js
const login = () => {
  return axiosInstance.get('/auth/login', {
    transformResponse: axios.defaults.transformResponse.concat(({ data }) => {
      return camelcaseKeys(data);
    }),
  });
};
```

1. when you provide a single function or array of function it overrides the default `transformResponse`, so you are responsible for serializing json string to js object.
2. When you concat with `axios.defaults.transformResponse` axios does the serializing for you , which is the default behaviour and lets you add your own changes.

Comment: Wow, this is super bad solution from axios team. Thanks for help!